# a textbox inside a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

- in my c# wpf windows application .. i want to establish a space to write a history of some items as bulleted points.
- i put a textbox inside scrollviewer to be able to write what i want ... but i faced 3 troubles:
- first trouble: i can't add bullets to my text ??
- second trouble: my text go in one vertical direction from left to right .. so vertical scrollbar appear while horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear ,i.e. i want to use the horizontal scrollbar only ...i want to see my whole text in horizontal way only
- third trouble: pressing Enter doesn't move to next new line
- waiting for your advices ..thank you
  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want (minus the bulletpoints) with a TextBox you need to set a few properties, to allow for new lines on Enter set AcceptsReturn="True" , to allow wrapping of the text set TextWrapping="Wrap" and so on. You can do the same with a RichTextBox

```
        <TextBox Width="300" 
             Height="300" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             AcceptsReturn="True" 
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        </TextBox>
```

Comment: NP, glad I could help. Keep posting questions, it helps more people than one usually thinks :)

Answer (score 0):

To get bullets, I would use a `RichTextBox`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands.togglebullets.aspx) is a link to the command that you can execute to insert bullets. Then to allow newlines, there is a property `AcceptsReturn` which you need to set to true.